# Can I automatically add related posts to my posts on Wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com, widgets

Is there a widget or some other feature which will automatically add related posts to my blog posts on Wordpress.com?

I know that I can use Zemanta (in my case, via [a Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fejeknoakjeblidffkajbioncodnmhge)) to add related posts one-by-one. That might actually be all I want to do, but was interested in also exploring an automatic feature if it is available natively on Wordpress.com?

Back in 2008, a feature was released called "Possibly Related Posts" (see [Possibly an Announcement](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/possibly-an-announcement/)). Has this feature been discontinued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install any custom plugins on Wordpress.com for related posts. Unfortunately.

<strike>The one I've used and abused is called [Yet Another Related Posts Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/). It's highly customizable, free, and has the widget that you want.</strike>

As of June 2012, there is no feature built-in to Wordpress.com to display related posts.

Comment: Yes, I've used this on a self-hosted Wordpress site, but my question is about a Wordpress.com hosted site. I don't believe I have the ability to install that plugin, right?

Comment: right... you cannot. Updating answer

Comment: thanks @ShannonWagner for the date helper... I'm trying to make that a standard on my answers lately.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically? Apparently not any more.

However, you can achieve what you want on a per-post basis by using the magic of shortcodes. Specifically, the [display posts](http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/) shortcode.

> Add the shortcode [display-posts] in a post or page, and use the arguments to query based on tag, category, post type, and many other possibilities.

Depending on what you want to use for your "related" criteria, say a category, it's as simple as adding to your post (probably at the end):

```
[display-posts category="{category name}"]
```

You can also use tags, post author, and some rather complex taxonomy queries.

More details at [WordPress support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/).